# use jquery live or on for a sequenced load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading a number of images using ajax and want to bind them to appear in sequence. To do this WITHOUT ajax, i'm just doing this:

```
$(".sequenced-fadein").hide().each(function(index, el){
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(el).fadeIn(1234)
    }, 500 * (index+1));
});
```

but I can't see how to bind this if the objects are loaded using ajax (other than putting everything into `function reBindThingsThatMightBeDynamicallyLoaded()` and calling it after each `$.get()`, which just seems clunky. I'm sure it's something so simple that I am overlooking it - I already tried `.on("ready", function () { ..` but jquery doesn't support ready binding to live/on events afaik.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in the ajax callback function.

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
    $(data).hide().appendTo('#container').each(function(index, el){
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(el).fadeIn(1234)
        }, 500 * (index+1));
    });
});
```

Comment: If this was the only thing being bound within the externally loaded document then I would, however the images are part of markup (external, not mine, can't change, can't partial), and there are other classes that I want to bind things to as well. Figuring this out for one class is the step to a full solution for me.